# How to update value for TextField using StreamBuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, sqflite, rxdart

I have a `textfield` and i am using `sqflite` database in my app. The `sqflite` has a value which i need to assign to my `textfield`

Here is my `textfield` code

```
 StreamBuilder<String>(
    stream: patientHealthFormBloc.doctorName,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      return TextFormField(
        initialValue: patientHealthFormBloc.doctorNameValue,
        onChanged: (value) {
          patientHealthFormBloc.doctorNameChanged(value);
        },
        ...
```

Now in the `initstate` method of my class, i am fetching value from database.
It being an asynchronous operation so it takes time.

My bloc class has a code like follows

```
Function(String) get doctorNameChanged => _doctorName.sink.add;
```

so as soon as i receive value from database i call following

```
doctorNameChanged("valuefromdatabase");
```

but i cant see the value in my textfield. Also there is a value present in my database.
Is it possible to update the value without using `TextEditingController` or `setState`. I ma trying to avoid those as my class is divided in lot of chuncks and way too complicated to use any of the above
I have tried using same approach with `RadioButton` and `CheckBox` and they seem to update properly.
The value is also updated in  `_doctorName.stream.value` which is present in the database but the `textfield` does not show any data. Also i tried changing color of `textfield` so there is no issue there as well as i am able to see what i type.

I have made a small demo of the app https://github.com/PritishSawant/demo/tree/master/lib

Instead of using `sqflite`, i am using `shared preferences` but the problem persists

Comment: Try removing "initialValue: patientHealthFormBloc.doctorNameValue", and start it in the "initialData" from the StreamBuilder

Comment: @Stel Thanks but does not work

Comment: You can use the TextEditingController(text: )

Comment: @ChinkySight I am using Stream to avoid TextEditingController. The app is complicated and using TextEditingController is not feasible

Comment: In your example you aren't using the snapshot at all. What data do you expect to extract from it to use in your TextFormField? Why can't you use a TextEditingController?

Comment: If you want to preemptively fill a TextFormField with a value from a database which the user will then change and save that change to the database, why are you using a Stream? It seems like you are adding complexity where it isn't required.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain what you are trying to achieve. Why you want to change a TextFormField's value in real time, taking into account that it's Widget that will be actively be used by the user. Are you expecting to change the value while the user is typing? It's a bit confusing to understand since typically you load the existing value into a TextField and then let the user edit that and save it.

Comment: @JoãoSoares When user comes to the textfield for the first time, he types something and click save, the textfield data is saved in sqflite. Now when he comes to that textfield on the next app reopen, i want to display the value which he has already previously typed. I don't think the question is confusing to understand?

Comment: Ok, then if you are using Streams just because of Bloc, why don't you just listen to the Stream on your initState and use setState to fill in the initialValue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK so i finally found the solution to my problem.

Following is my code, I have just used `SharedPreferences` instead of `sqflite` for the below example.Same thing can be done with `sqflite`

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  MyBloc myBloc = MyBloc();
  TextEditingController myController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    myBloc?.close();
    myController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    AppPreferences.setString("data", "this is my data");
    AppPreferences.getString("data").then((value){
      myBloc.dataChanged(value);
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: myBloc.data,
           builder: (context,snapshot){

            debugPrint(snapshot.data);
            myController.value = myController.value.copyWith(text: myBloc.dataValue);

            return TextFormField(
              controller: myController,
              onChanged: (value){
                myBloc.dataChanged(value);
              },
            );
           },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This an extremely over engineered solution. I wish you had explained what exactly you wanted to achieve originally instead of wanting us to fix your specific solution. As I commented on your question, you seem to be wanting to do real time updates to a TextField that may be being used actively by the user. This is very strange and likely bad UX.

Comment: @JoãoSoares Can you post your solution. I am more than happy to award the bounty and accept your solution if its better than mine. I have just posted an easier solution so everyone can understand but in reality my app requires syncing with sqflite as well as firestore so it may look over engineered to you

Comment: If you can explain why you want to Stream (update) the value of a TextFieldForm at the same time the user might be using it, I may be able to help you. Syncing with SQFlite and Firestore has no involvement in my claim that the solution you presented is over-engineered.

Comment: I have read the question multiple times already and have seen the code you shared on GitHub. Your explanation speaks of what you want to do and how you want the code written. It does not explain why you want to have a TextFormField being filled in that way with data Streaming or the premise for that behavior.

Comment: Based on your explanation, my understanding is that you want a TextFormField to be streaming the current value on your database. Then you expect that when the user saves the form and the database is updated the value in your TextFormField get updated from the database. Even though it is already updated because your used just typed in the new value.

Comment: Did you attempt my proposed solution?

Comment: @Nudge It's great that this code worked out for you, but I only wanted to let you know that the question you asked and the solution you found are contradicting each other. in question you clearly said you didn;t wanted to use `TextEditController` if possible. When @João Soares and @Chinky Sight  suggested using it. you said it's not feasible to use it. Why a sudden change in requirement. Even If it is a legit change in requirement, why not just remove the question. Since the solution you came up with was simple and was suggested to you over and over again in the comments.

Comment: I would suggest that you try out the solution by @JoãoSoares and Accept that answer if worked. since it's pretty simple and now it's okay to use the `TextEditController`.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems the user did not want to attribute the bounty despite the effort of several users to help. Which is unfortunate.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following approach:

```
StreamBuilder<String>(
  stream: patientHealthFormBloc.doctorName,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    String doctorName = patientHealthFormBloc.doctorNameValue;
    if(snapshot.hasData){
      doctorName = snapshot.data/*(your name string from the stream)*/;
    } 
    return TextFormField(
      initialValue: doctorName,
      onChanged: (value) {
        patientHealthFormBloc.doctorNameChanged(value);
      },
    ...
```

Comment: are you receiving new names in stream?

Comment: are you receiving the same new names in `builder: (context, snapshot)`?

Comment: When i type a text, i receive the typed text. At the initial stage when i fetching from db then it is printing the db value.The StreamBuilder is working fine and the value updates when i manually type but it does not update when it is fetched from database

Comment: For you to get refreshed data from database, you'll need it inside a streambuilder with changes from method that return the database results

Comment: @Stel but it works for radiobutton and checkbox, why not for textfield. there is not need for another stream builder for database as i have already added a streambuilder for textfield and changing it value when i get data from db

Comment: @Nudge make sure that you are using the `doctorNameChanged` method on the same bloc instance which you are listening from in the first place. If that's not a problem, this is probably something other than just update of text field.

Comment: @HarshvardhanJoshi I am using the same bloc instance

Comment: in that case something else is happening.. can you post more code ? where you are fetching data from db and sending to bloc?

Comment: @HarshvardhanJoshi in the initstate method

Comment: @HarshvardhanJoshi I have added a demo app link source code in the question, please check if you have time

Comment: Changing the value of a `TextFormField`'s `initialValue` property will not make it change the current value being displayed. It will only change on a full rebuild.

Comment: @JoãoSoares What the solution then??

Answer (score 1):

What was suggesting in my comments was something like this:

```
TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

@override
void initState() {
  patientHealthFormBloc.doctorName.listen((snapshot){
    setState((){
      _textEditingController.text = snapshot;
    });
  });
  super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
      TextFormField(
        controller: _textEditingController,
        onChanged: (value) {
          patientHealthFormBloc.doctorNameChanged(value);
        },
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

I didn't want to write this answer without understanding why you didn't want to use a TextEditingController or a setState. But this should achieve what you want while using the Bloc pattern.

Comment: I had this thought in the beginning, but since the question quoted and @Nudge was insisting on not using the `TextEditController`, so I scraped that Idea. It's great that only by using the controller the solution becomes simple and small to work accurately. Great Job.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it. Unfortunately the user seemed adamant on sticking to his own idea and not attempt to write a proper solution, as such they decided not to attribute the correct response or the bounty.

Comment: When I used this approach I got this warning `Another exception was thrown: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.` It is working but I am just bothered

Comment: It sould be related to whichever state management solution you are using.